# Can I install Ubuntu in Android tablet?

Tags: tablet, 22.10

I was just wondering if I could install Ubuntu 22.10 in my Android tablet? Will it works exactly like it does in my laptop? I have 6gb of ram in the tablet and a decent mid range processor? Will it be good enough to do all the basics task?

Comment: No, there is not an official version of Ubuntu that runs on mobile devices like phones and tablets. You can look into Ubuntu Touch, but that is not on-topic here because it's not an official flavour of Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there any form of Linux that can be installed in tab?

Comment: we only know about Ubuntu. Your q is better suited on a site that supports your tablet and is about custom roms.

Answer (score 0):

Not officially/natively. There is no port. However, after searching a bit, I found numerous tutorials. One stood out and does not require rooting at all, which is one of two services: Debian NoRoot and UserLAnd, both being PlayStore apps that let you run Linux distros.